# Use xvfb to automate X program

Tags: linux, xorg, xvfb

I sadly have to use this proprietary program that bundles a camera driver. I want to perform a specific action with it, which involves clicking a few buttons. And there is no CLI.

So, what is the easiest way to automate this?
I though of using xvfb to open the program in a fake X environment, but then how would I go about performing input operations? It could be click pixel at (x, y), but it would be even nicer if I could reference buttons and menu items.

If there is a simpler way to do it, please tell! I'm not sure xvfb is the correct method. I don't even know the actual name of what I'm trying to accomplish, so searching is very hard...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`xdotool`](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool) which can fake keyboard/mouse input, window management, and more.

Sample usage based on the [`install_mt4-xdot.sh`](https://github.com/EA31337/FX-MT-VM/blob/master/scripts/install_mt4-xdot.sh) script which installs Windows app under wine:

```
wine setup.exe &
echo "Waiting to initialize..."
while ! WID=$(xdotool search --name "Setup"); do
  sleep 2
done

echo "Sending installer keystrokes..." >&2
xdotool key --window $WID --delay 500 space Tab Tab Tab Return Tab Tab Tab space Alt+n

echo "Waiting for installer to finish..." >&2
xwininfo -id $WID -tree
while pgrep -l setup; do sleep 5; done

echo "Waiting program to start..." >&2
while ! WID=$(xdotool search --name "Title - *"); do
  sleep 2
done

echo "Closing application..." >&2
xdotool key --window $WID --delay 500 Escape Escape Alt+f x
sleep 1
wineserver -k
echo "Installation successful." >&2
```

Using `xdotool` you can control any app or window.

However if it's wine app only ran under Xvfb, you can also consider using [`winetricks`](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks).